# Interesting problem involving gradient

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f$ be a differentiable function such that $\nabla f(1,1)=(1,-3)$ and $\nabla f(1,0)=(-3,3)$. Define the function, $$h(x,y)=f(x^2,x^2-y^2).$$ Find, $||\nabla h(1,1)||$.

My attempt:

We have that, $f_x(1,1)=1$, $f_y(1,1)=-3$, $f_x(1,0)=-3$ and $f_y(1,0)=3$. How can I relate the derivatives of $h$ and $f$? I tried to use the chain rule but I couldn't find the value of $||\nabla h(1,1)||$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the chain rule we have

$$h_x(x,y)=f_x(x^2,x^2-y^2) \cdot 2x+f_y(x^2,x^2-y^2) \cdot 2x$$

and

$$h_y(x,y)=f_x(x^2,x^2-y^2) \cdot 0+f_y(x^2,x^2-y^2) \cdot (-2y).$$

Now compute $\nabla h(1,1)$ and then $||\nabla h(1,1)||.$

Answer (score 1):

You have $h(x, y) = f(u(x), v(x, y))$ with $u(x) = x^2$ and $v(x, y) = x^2 - y^2$.
The chain rules tells you that
$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(x, y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(u(x), v(x, y))u'(x) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(u(x), v(x, y)) \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x, y)$
and
$\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(x, y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(u(x), v(x, y)) \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(x, y)$.
You should be able to find these expressions, then substitute $x = y = 1$.